# JavaScript not recognizing variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and struggling to figure out why this piece of code isn't working for me.

Essentially I'm defining a variable, yet when I go to use that variable in an IF or Switch statement, it doesn't seem to be able to match the contents of the variable. No errors, the IF statement just doesn't get satisfied. While with the Switch, it always falls through to the default setting, as it can't match the contents.

I have a Print statement in place after the variable is defined, and it does display the contents of the variable correctly.

I'm really at a loss as to why the print can return the value of the variable, yet the IF and Switch can't find it.

Below is the snippet I'm working from. The variable is "strWilma", which doesn't get reflected properly in the  Print second value statement, but not in the IF.

```
for (var i=0; i < Flinstones.length; i++)
    {
         if (Flinstones[i].startsWith("?")) 
        {   
            // Convert the Secondary field map to a Properties item, for easier navigation
            var objSecondaryFieldMap = PropertiesFromString(strSecondaryFieldMap);

            //      Map all of the Secondary values
            var arraySecondaryFields = objSecondaryFieldMap.keys();
            while (arraySecondaryFields.hasMoreElements())

            {
                strFred = arraySecondaryFields.nextElement();
                strWilma = objSecondaryFieldMap.get(strFred);

                print("TargetType:" + Object.prototype.toString.call(strFred));
                print("SourceType:" + Object.prototype.toString.call(strWilma));
                print("Text  Type:" + Object.prototype.toString.call("hardcoded value"));

                print("First  Value:" + objItem.getNewFieldValue(Flinstones[i].substring(1))  );    
                print("Second Value:" + strWilma ); 

                if (objItem.getNewFieldValue(Flinstones[i].substring(1)) == strWilma)

                //if (objItem.getNewFieldValue(Flinstones[i].substring(1)) == "hardcoded value") // WORKS

                {
                    print("It Worked!!!");  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should declare your variables, and use JSLint/JSHint and use strict.

Comment: what does the console output look like when you try to run this?

Comment: Are you using the SpiderMonkey console? Otherwise most implementations don't have `print` and a bunch of other stuff you used. (Unless by print you meant the print window).

Comment: I would start off by using `var` when declaring your variables. For example, instead of `strWilma = objSecondaryFieldMap.get(strFred);`, change it to `var strWilma = objSecondaryFieldMap.get(strFred);`. I'm not saying this will solve your problem but this is considered as 'best practice' for JavaScript.

Comment: I have tried with var strWilma = objSecondaryFieldMap.get(strFred); with the same result.

I should have mentioned, this script isn't for execution in a browser, but rather is utilized by another stand alone application. 

The print statements write the messages out the the log of that application. It is there I can see the messages, and it shows the strWilma variable as being displayed properly.


Thanks again.